# Stored procedure locally very fast, but doesn't work on the server (possible deadlock?)

Tags: sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMultipleChangeLogs
(
    @ChangeLogs dbo.ChangeLogs readonly,
    @ChangeLogItems dbo.ChangeLogItems readonly,
    @BatchSize int = 300
)
AS

DECLARE @Map AS TABLE
                (
                    TempId int,
                    InsertedId int
                )

DECLARE @startIndex int = 0;
DECLARE @numRows int;
select @numRows = count(*) from @ChangeLogs;
    WHILE @startIndex <= @numRows
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                BEGIN TRY
                    MERGE INTO dbo.ChangeLogs USING (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM @ChangeLogs
                        ORDER BY Id
                        OFFSET @startIndex ROWS
                            FETCH NEXT @BatchSize ROWS ONLY
                    ) AS source
                    ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT (
                            State,
                            DateTime,
                            UpdatedBy
                        )
                                VALUES (
                                   source.State,
                                   source.DateTime,
                                   source.UpdatedBy
                               )
                        OUTPUT source.Id, inserted.Id
                            INTO @Map (TempId, InsertedId);

                    INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeLogItems(
                                                    ChangeLogId
                                                  , PropertyName
                                                  , OldValue
                                                  , NewValue
                    )
                    SELECT InsertedId
                         , PropertyName
                         , OldValue
                         , NewValue
                    FROM @ChangeLogItems as OD
                             INNER JOIN @Map as Map
                                        ON(OD.ChangeLogId = Map.TempId);
                    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                END CATCH
                SET @startIndex += @BatchSize;
        END
```

The short description of the SP: I need to save parent object which is ChangeLog and then take Id from it and save children with this Id as foreign key.

This function locally works perfectly with huge data, also it works perfectly on the server with low amount of income data. But when I have 20 thousand of records which needs to be processed then it starts to show me this in the activity monitor on the server:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBEgE.png)

When this happens, it is impossible to Request any data from the ChangeLogItems, ChangeLog tables. When I try to request data from them it gives me this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfRYJ.png)

We can consider the server is not power enough, but the strange thing that sometimes this SP procedure works on the server too and with huge data. Also the server load is no more then 50-60% while this procedure working.

My own suspicion - the deadlock on the server, since during that time
Any suggestions are welcome :-)

I tried to implement batching, currently it works using batches, but the issue still remaining

Comment: I believe you mean blocking rather than deadlocking. Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Hi, @DanGuzman, thank you for the suggestion here is the link: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJXCi3P4n

Comment: you might wanna index your @map table variable

Comment: Aside... the separate MERGE and INSERT statements could be consolidated into one nested statement. i.e.: the OUTPUT of the MERGE can be used directly as a row source for the INSERT into ChangeLogItems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all thank you Charlieface for the suggestion, I removed the batching and added the PK to the @Map table. However I still was struggling with performance of this SP. The slowest part was in this place:

```
   INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeLogItems(
    ChangeLogId
  , PropertyName
  , OldValue
  , NewValue
)
SELECT Map.InsertedId
     , OD.PropertyName
     , OD.OldValue
     , OD.NewValue
FROM @ChangeLogItems as OD
INNER JOIN @Map as Map ON OD.ChangeLogId = Map.TempId;
```

The reason why, it is because of the join statement. For example we have 1500 rows in ChangeLogs table, but at the same time we have move than 15 000 rows in the ChangeLogsItems table. Because of this huge number of relating items during the joining Logical reads were just flying to the moon and it led to the problem with slow processing.

In order to avoid it, we implemented batching on the backend, so each batch contains 300 rows in parent table and only those records which are belong to this parent's rows. By doing so, we managed to greatly reduce the amount of Logical Reads and consequently this improved the performance of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need batching here, it's just causing more problems due to scanning the tables multiple times. You just need to make sure everything is correctly indexed.

Index the `@Map` table variable by `TempId`, as shown. And the `dbo.ChangeLogItems` table type should also have a primary key on `(ChangeLogId, PropertyName)`.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE InsertMultipleChangeLogs
(
    @ChangeLogs dbo.ChangeLogs readonly,
    @ChangeLogItems dbo.ChangeLogItems readonly
)
AS

DECLARE @Map AS TABLE
(
    TempId int PRIMARY KEY,   -- NEW primary key
    InsertedId int NOT NULL
);

MERGE INTO dbo.ChangeLogs
USING @ChangeLogs AS source
ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        State,
        DateTime,
        UpdatedBy
    )
    VALUES (
        source.State,
        source.DateTime,
        source.UpdatedBy
    )
OUTPUT source.Id, inserted.Id
INTO @Map (TempId, InsertedId);

INSERT INTO dbo.ChangeLogItems(
    ChangeLogId
  , PropertyName
  , OldValue
  , NewValue
)
SELECT Map.InsertedId
     , OD.PropertyName
     , OD.OldValue
     , OD.NewValue
FROM @ChangeLogItems as OD
INNER JOIN @Map as Map ON OD.ChangeLogId = Map.TempId;
```

Comment: Hi @Charlieface! Thank you for the suggestion, as soon as I try it I will post the results here